# Prompt as me count all the rows from a file ? I understand that in a cycle but a verification clause should be?

Tags: c#

1 option is already there, but need another

---

```
using (StreamReader str = new StreamReader(@"d:\alfa.txt", Encoding.Default))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            Line = str.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better I think to use file.Simple ReadLines method and linq in

int count = File.ReadLines(@"d:\alfa.txt").Count();

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`File.ReadLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx) method and simple linq

```
int count = File.ReadLines(@"d:\alfa.txt").Count();
```

Answer (score 1):

Until you reach the end of stream.

```
int count = 0;
using (StreamReader str = new StreamReader(@"d:\alfa.txt", Encoding.Default))
{
    while(!str.EndOfStream)
    {
        Line = str.ReadLine();
        count++:
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If the string is the sentence :
     if(mas[i] == '.') count++; 
You must copy the file from all the characters in the mas and then check the condition .

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to say.... What is `mas`, where does `i` come from? What does `You must copy the file from all the characters in the mas` mean?